# using jQuery UI buttons outside the framework

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to use the jQuery button elements as "standalone" - without the usage of the `.button()` function (including the rollover effect). Assigning the `.button()` to each individually would be quite complicated...

What I am looking for is a solution to either use the direct CSS classes of jQuery UI to create some sort of "combined" class, something like: *(Notice: "import" used to describe only, I know it's invalid)*

```
.ui-button-custom {
    "import" ui-state-default;
}
.ui-button-custom:hover {
    "import" ui-state-hover;
}
```

Other possible way would be to apply `.button()` dynamically to specific elements, i.e. something like:

```
// gets all elements with "custom-button" in the class attr
$("a[class*=custom-button").each(function(){
  var t=$(this);
  // apply .button() to all of them
  t.button({
    icons: {
      // get the icon dynamically from the class name:
      // strip off "custom-button-" and the rest is the icon name
      primary: t.attr('class').substring(lastIndexOf('custom-button-'))
    }
  });
});

<a href="#" class="custom-button-ui-icon-refresh">Log In</a>
```

Notice: This is just an outline of what an solution could look like. I have just a little experience with jQuery UI so maybe someone with more experience could point out problems with this idea...

My questions are:

1. Is there any other way how to do this?
2. If not & if pure CSS is not possible - how to complete the JS above (if possible)? I know that the `.button()` uses `.next()` which I quite don't understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting I finally found the solution:

```
<a href="#" id="sss" class="custom-button-ui-icon-refresh">Log In</a>
<br />
<a href="#" id="sssaaa" class="custom-button-ui-icon-circle-close">Log In</a>
<br />
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a[class*='custom-button']").each(function(){
  var t=$(this);
  var icon_class = t.attr('class');
  var icon = icon_class.replace('custom-button-','');
  // alert(icon);
  // apply .button() to all of them
  t.button({
    icons: {
      // get the icon dynamically from the class name:
      // strip off "custom-button-" and the rest is the icon name
      primary: icon
    }
  });
  if ( t.text() == "" ){
     t.css("height", "25px");
     t.css("width", "25px");
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simple add more than one class to your custom button? Somthing like:

```
<a href="#" class="custom-button-ui ui-state-default">Log In</a>.
```

Then with jquery set an mouseover/mouseout function to add/remove the ui-state-hover class

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".custom-button-ui").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-default').addClass('ui-state-hover');
  });
  $(".custom-button-ui").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover').addClass('ui-state-default');
  });
});
</script>
```

or even

```
<a href="#" class="custom-button-ui">Log In</a>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".custom-button-ui").addClass('ui-state-default');
  $(".custom-button-ui").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-default').addClass('ui-state-hover');
  });
  $(".custom-button-ui").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover').addClass('ui-state-default');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this would be usable to change default/hover states only. however, I need to get all the behavior of the buttons including the icons...

Comment: Yes I can see that it would mean a lot of housekeeping to get the right look and feel.

Comment: thanx for the edit my friend, however - how could this produce individual icons for each button??